# Having bash print the files it sources

Tags: bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm attempting to discover how some virtualenvwrapper function definitions are getting into my shell. (More specifically, because they're the old version, and I want to get rid of them, put in a new version.)

I've grepped for sourcing stuff in my ~/.bashrc, I've even checked that going

```
env -i HOME=/tmp bash
```

does not have the definitions, which is true, so I'm pretty sure it's not the system bashrc.

So, bash when setting up the shell sources a number of files like:

```
source .bashrc
```

and

```
source .bash_aliases
```

And so on. But is there anyway to have bash print the names of files it sources, so I can try to work out where this sourcing is happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing

```
set -x
```

before

```
source .bashrc
```

would give a trace of commands being executed.

In order to filter `source` from the output, say

```
source .bashrc 2>&1 | grep source
```

Comment: I ended up with `env -i HOME=/tmp bash -ic "set -x; source /home/coiax/.bashrc" 2>&1 | less` but the magic is in set -x, so I'll let you have it.

Answer (score 2):

How about run bash in debug mode?

```
bash -x
```

Also you can imitate login with -l

```
bash -x -l
```

With that you could check how things happen.

And also, see if the array variable [BASH_SOURCE](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-BASH_005fSOURCE) could be helpful.